# Cursor can sit in unreachable columns

Tags: virtualedit

Some recent plugin or Vim upgrade appears to have enabled a new feature:

> When moving up/down or clicking, the cursor can now rest anywhere in the window, including over character cells far to the right of where the line has ended.

What is this feature called, and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out a plugin I had recently installed was doing:

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

I could easily return to the normal behaviour by running:

```
:set virtualedit=
```

You can read the [documentation for the `virtualedit` option here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'virtualedit').

Comment: That's a pretty silly thing for a plugin to do btw.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It was a [pretty crazy plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/microViche) which I had dropped into my folder out of curiosity. For sure, it could be better behaved.

Comment: Yeah, that should use `setlocal` only for a filetype or on demand, rather than `set` globally.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker This is one of our problems. The "obvious" way to do things in Vimscript are frequently not the best-practice way. There are [guides](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/) for how to write well-behaved plugins, but it's always an uphill struggle against the path of least resistance. Perhaps what we need is an inbuilt/bundled [***linter***](https://www.google.de/search?q=vimscript+linter) to assist plugin developers. You know, like [Clippy](http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/vindicated/2016/10/31/31-clippy.w710.h473.jpg) :-p